# How to get the list of source repositories of a user/organisation on GitHub?

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-api

I wanna get the list of repositories of a user or an organisation on GitHub, but excluding forked, mirrored or archived repos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) you can do the following to filter public repos:

```py
from github import Github

g = Github()

user = g.get_user("<username>") # target user
repos = user.get_repos()

non_forks = []
for repo in user.get_repos():
    if repo.fork is False:
        non_forks.append(repo.name)

print(non_forks)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've written a small script that does the job perfectly

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import readline, sys, os, requests

import click
from github import Github

g = Github()

def userexists(username):
    addr = "https://api.github.com/users/" + username
    response = requests.get(addr)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        return False
    else:
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return True

def printrepos(repos):
        original_repos = []
        for repo in repos:
            if repo.fork is False and repo.archived is False:
                print(repo.clone_url)

@click.command()
@click.argument('username')
def main(username):
    if userexists(username):
        user = g.get_user(username)
        repos = user.get_repos()
        printrepos(repos)
    else:
        print("Username doesn't exist")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Typo in ```response = requests.get(addr)```. It would be sth like: 
```response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
        if response.status == 404:
            return False
        else:
            if response.status == 200: return True
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub

is a python library for interacting with the Github API. From the readme:

```
from github import Github

# First create a Github instance:

# using username and password
g = Github("user", "password")

# or using an access token
g = Github("access_token")

# Github Enterprise with custom hostname
g = Github(base_url="https://{hostname}/api/v3", login_or_token="access_token")

# Then play with your Github objects:
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print(repo.name)
```

The Repository object has properties that allow checking whether the repo is archived, a fork, or a mirror:

```
repo.archived // is repo archived?
repo.fork // is repo a fork?
repo.mirror_url // return the url of the mirrored repo, if applicable
```

Comment: `repo.fork` is a `bool` for me not a callable `repo.fork()`.

Comment: Then leave the parentheses off. In the code it is defined as a function with `@property`. Maybe I got my python syntactic sugar incorrect. https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/37122cf2bbde825e57e78ee37171bab150802eca/github/Repository.py#L310

Comment: @zaxishere It's a bool for anybody else too.

Comment: @zaxishere I fixed the answer.